# Draw overlap of 3 circles on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to draw the following image on an HTML5 canvas without a temporary canvas:

[image]

With a temporary canvas it's easy, because I can handle the overlaps independently like you can see here:

**[Check this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaFkU/1/)**.

```
// init
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var tempCanvas = document.getElementById('tempCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

// draw circle function
var drawCircle = function( c, color ) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc( c.x, c.y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
}

// draw overlap function
var drawOverlap = function( c1, c2, color ) {
  tempCtx.clearRect( 0, 0, 300, 300 );
  // first circle
  tempCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  tempCtx.beginPath();
  tempCtx.arc( c1.x, c1.y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
  tempCtx.fillStyle = color;
  tempCtx.fill();
  // second circle
  tempCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  tempCtx.beginPath();
  tempCtx.arc( c2.x, c2.y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
  tempCtx.fill();
  // draw on main canvas
  ctx.drawImage( tempCanvas, 0, 0 );
}

// circle objects
var c1 = { x:100, y: 200 };
var c2 = { x:180, y: 200 };
var c3 = { x:140, y: 140 };

// draw background
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect( 0, 0, 300, 300 );
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fill();

// draw circles
drawCircle( c1, 'grey' );
drawCircle( c2, 'white' );
drawCircle( c3, 'white' );

// draw overlaps
drawOverlap( c1, c2, 'red' );
drawOverlap( c1, c3, 'blue' );
drawOverlap( c2, c3, 'blue' );
```

Do you know a way to draw this without a second canvas? Thanks a lot.

---

### EDIT:

I solved it thanks to @user13500. There are still ugly borders but it's very fast:

**[Check this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USt7C/)**

Comment: I used the KinectJS framework which has a layer system! http://kineticjs.com. Realy nice framework for canvas use!

Comment: Thank you @Timo002. I know kineticjs and love it, but in this case the project is to advanced to implement another framework.

Comment: like @markE said, why not just use an offscreen canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ai, my head hurts.

Not a quite a solution. Not one at all I guess. But if we do not care about the background we have this:

<strike>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/6StCe/2/)</strike> Updated to new version as below.

Giving us this:

[image]

Tried to solve this using only `globalCompositeOperation` ;-P

---

### Edit:

OK. Moving away from it for a few minutes and here we go again. This time with this as result. There is still the issue with stray lines around the circle red:

[image]

Though it might not be what you are after, it is here ;-) [@markE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke) is in another realm when it comes to authority on the subject.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/6StCe/)

Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var ct = [
    'source-over',         //  0
    'source-in',           //  1
    'source-out',          //  2
    'source-atop',         //  3
    'destination-over',    //  4
    'destination-in',      //  5
    'destination-out',     //  6
    'destination-atop',    //  7
    'lighter',             //  8
    'darker',              //  9
    'copy',                // 10
    'xor'                  // 11
];

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[0];
ctx.fillStyle = "#888";
ctx.arc(100,200,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[6];
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.arc(180,200,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[11];
ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
ctx.arc(100,200,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[4];
ctx.fillStyle = "#888";
ctx.arc(100,200,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[9];
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.arc(180,200,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[11];
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.arc(140,140,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[4];
ctx.fillStyle = "#00f";
ctx.arc(140,140,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ct[4];
ctx.rect( 0, 0, 300, 300 );
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Great one! I was playing around like you for hours today, but unfortunately the background is important.

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, figured as much ;), but gave it a go. I have to admit I experience a challenge when it comes to composing the various `globalCompositeOperation` methods at disposal using the eye of the mind.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. It's super fluid, thanks a lot. unfortunately the borders are a bit ugly, but it's ok for the moment. Great work!

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, I'm pounding at how to get rid of the borders etc. But guess it is a start.

Comment: One more thing: Because there are hundreds of other things on the canvas I can't use xor, because it's too expensive to render the whole menu in every frame. That means I always need to render the background first. Do you think it's possible to waive xor's?

Comment: @tomatentobi: Believe that would be rather hard. But I'm not fluent enough in canvas to say definitively either or.

Comment: @tomatentobi: There could of course also be other ways to optimize, but hard to say from this Q. Perhaps a candidate for another question where you elaborate more around what actually is going on. (As FPS rendering, animation?, goal.) This could obviously quickly also become rather broad and complex question I guess, but - perhaps there are some gurus (or other) out there with some valuable hints.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought I keep the question as simple as possible, but it's more komplex than I thought. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a temporary canvas using clipping regions -- context.clip()

If you need, I can code the solution but since you know how to do compositing you can probably figure it out quickly ;)

But more importantly! ...

Why are you disabling your tool choices by not using a temporary canvas?

You could do document.createElement("canvas") to create a temporary canvas that's not even visible on the screen.

Comment: Thank you @markE. Maybe clipping regions is the solution. Let me play with this before I give you the checkmark ;) I don't just draw it but the circles are moving and I use requestAnimationFrame and hundreds of circles. Using a temporary canvas and 'copying' the clip to the main canvas is too expensive for 60 FPS.

Comment: Cool! FYI, before html canvas learned to be auto-double-buffered by itself a good technique for increasing performance was to maintain an offscreen canvas.  Draw the next animation on the offscreen canvas. When the next frame was required you'd just drawImage(offscreenCanvas).  Canvas-to-Canvas draws are very fast these days...especially since the process is really the GPU blitting the offscreen image data to the onscreen image data.  Good luck with your project! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @markE! I try to prerender the animation before the next frame, if I understand this right? Maybe it's a bit faster. Will take me some minutes...

Comment: Ok, clipping regions works and is a bit faster but still to slow. I'll check your prerendering idea.

Comment: unfortunately prerendering is too slow too, but thanks for your knowledge!

Comment: FWIW...I come up with these informal benchmarks for repeatedly drawing your 3 intersecting circles for 1000 times.  Compositing: IE=1149ms, Chrome=80ms, FF=2398ms(ouch!?).  Clipping: IE=1110ms, Chrome=159ms, FF=998ms.  And I also did 1000 times drawing with a pure math solution: IE=311ms, Chrome=75ms, FF=398ms.  In these quick tests I didn't try using an offscreen canvas.  That's because the performance benefit/non-benefit of an offscreen canvas varies greatly by what the rest of your code is doing.  Cheers!

Comment: Wow, thanks for testing. Interesting results! I also have to say that I use a big canvas with 2048 x 1536 pixels (iPad) and the circles are small like a radius of 50 pixels. Using compositing and clipping is much more expensive then compared to the pure math solution.